# Python Enumerate Function Auto Sorts

Tags: python

When I run this code here:

```
nums = [1,7,3,4,10]
sorts = nums
sorts.sort()
count=0
for i,e in enumerate(nums):
    print(i,e)
    if sorts[i] != e:
        count+=1

print(count)
```

the i and e values inside the enumerate loop seem to be auto sorted. However, once I remove the sorts.sort(), it doesn't auto sort. Why is this?

Comment: There's no "auto" sorting here. It's sorted because you sorted it. If you don't sort, it doesn't get sorted.

Comment: _However, once I remove the sorts.sort(), it doesn't auto sort._ Sorting sorts the list, not sorting doesn't sort the list. Can you clarify what the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

The name `nums` is a reference represents the [1,7,3,4,10] list.

Line 2, you create a new name `sorts` that also represents that same list.

Line 3, you use `sorts.sort()` to sort it, so it changes the same list that `nums` represented. Hence, it is not auto-sort.

If you remove the `sorts.sort()`, then the `nums` list will keep the same.

Comment: Then can you please explain what a better method of storing nuns in a separate vehicle

Comment: @Vibertex Khan What do you mean about a separate vehicle? It seems like you looking for a better solution way.

Answer (score 0):

well obviously. if you don't sort them then they will not be sorted.. the program doesn't update the list from run to run.

Answer (score 0):

You used a sort method. Remove it and you will get your values listed the way it is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

by declaring `sorts = nums` you've made a shallow copy of sorts and so by calling `sort()`, the references are sorted in memory and the nums list will be using those references. if you want a deep copy do this: `sorts = [i for i in nums]`. The enumerate function will of course always produce an incrementation

Comment: Are there any other ways of storing a copy of nums

Comment: `import copy` for the copy module and then run `lst2 = copy.deepcopy(lst1)`. Also I've learned from experience to never do this: `[]*n` because while it creates n number of lists, it copies the same list repeatedly